# Mysql is not running in xampp

Tags: php, mysql

When i install xampp then mysql is started
But now I am having trouble with mysql

My sql is not running

And error log is

```
2014-01-23 21:45:06 5264 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2014-01-23 21:45:06 15dc InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2014-01-23 21:45:06 5264 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2014-01-23 21:45:06 5264 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2014-01-23 21:45:06 5264 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2014-01-23 21:45:06 5264 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2014-01-23 21:45:06 5264 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2014-01-23 21:45:06 5264 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2014-01-23 21:45:06 5264 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2014-01-23 21:45:06 5264 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 0 and 0 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 2472401 in the ib_logfiles!
2014-01-23 21:45:06 5264 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2014-01-23 21:45:06 5264 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2014-01-23 21:45:06 5264 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2014-01-23 21:45:06 5264 [ERROR] InnoDB: Attempted to open a previously opened tablespace. Previous tablespace mysql/slave_relay_log_info uses space ID: 3 at filepath: .\mysql\slave_relay_log_info.ibd. Cannot open tablespace wordpress/wp_terms which uses space ID: 3 at filepath: .\wordpress\wp_terms.ibd
InnoDB: Error: could not open single-table tablespace file .\wordpress\wp_terms.ibd
InnoDB: We do not continue the crash recovery, because the table may become
InnoDB: corrupt if we cannot apply the log records in the InnoDB log to it.
InnoDB: To fix the problem and start mysqld:
InnoDB: 1) If there is a permission problem in the file and mysqld cannot
InnoDB: open the file, you should modify the permissions.
InnoDB: 2) If the table is not needed, or you can restore it from a backup,
InnoDB: then you can remove the .ibd file, and InnoDB will do a normal
InnoDB: crash recovery and ignore that table.
InnoDB: 3) If the file system or the disk is broken, and you cannot remove
InnoDB: the .ibd file, you can set innodb_force_recovery > 0 in my.cnf
InnoDB: and force InnoDB to continue crash recovery here.
```

How can i solve this problem

Comment: Which version(s) do you use?

Comment: You've got a series of suggestions in that output. Did you try any of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try deleting the ibdata1 file in: **C:\xampp\mysql\data**

Change 'C:\xampp' as per your xampp installation folder.
Please remember to restart xampp after following the step.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is on your **question**:

```
2014-01-23 21:45:06 5264 [ERROR] InnoDB: Attempted to open a previously opened tablespace. Previous tablespace mysql/slave_relay_log_info uses space ID: 3 at filepath: .\mysql\slave_relay_log_info.ibd. Cannot open tablespace wordpress/wp_terms which uses space ID: 3 at filepath: .\wordpress\wp_terms.ibd
InnoDB: Error: could not open single-table tablespace file .\wordpress\wp_terms.ibd
InnoDB: We do not continue the crash recovery, because the table may become
InnoDB: corrupt if we cannot apply the log records in the InnoDB log to it.
InnoDB: To fix the problem and start mysqld:
InnoDB: 1) If there is a permission problem in the file and mysqld cannot
InnoDB: open the file, you should modify the permissions.
InnoDB: 2) If the table is not needed, or you can restore it from a backup,
InnoDB: then you can remove the .ibd file, and InnoDB will do a normal
InnoDB: crash recovery and ignore that table.
InnoDB: 3) If the file system or the disk is broken, and you cannot remove
InnoDB: the .ibd file, you can set innodb_force_recovery > 0 in my.cnf
InnoDB: and force InnoDB to continue crash recovery here.
```

To put simply, mysql cannot read your .\wordpress\wp_terms.ibd file because of improper shutdown and there is a possibility that the file is corrupted.

If you dont need that database just follow step 3